# Bundle products not added into cart in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I create a bundle products with many group products inside bundle product, where user can also change the qty of group product inside bundle, all group products have qty more than 10 ,but the problem is that its not adding to cart.
Error shows [image: click here] screenshot

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It was a caching/SID issue!

Symptoms to reproduce: Magento Blocks HTML caching is turned on (only when turned on)

A SID parameter was being added to the URL that I couldn't see and was being added in between query parameters in a way that messed everything up.

How to fix, add '_nosid' => true to URL params:

$params = array('_query'=> $query,'qty' => 1, '_nosid' => true);
Then the add to cart URL can be retrieved by

Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product, $params)